# Error:uncaught exception, not enoughh argument

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I got the following error, what is the problem?  How should I solve this issue:

```
**Error:** uncaught exception: [Exception... "Not enough arguments"  nsresult: "0x80570001 (NS_ERROR_XPC_NOT_ENOUGH_ARGS)"  location: "JS frame :: http://localhost:90/MARCON/createjob.cfm?job=exists&jobnumber=info10-1 :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 704"  data: no]
```

I have this code, how can I use `Send()` to avoid above error?

```
Ext.lib.Ajax = function() {        
        var activeX = ['MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0',
                       'MSXML2.XMLHTTP',
                       'Microsoft.XMLHTTP'];


        // private
        function setHeader(o) {
            var conn = o.conn,
                prop;

            function setTheHeaders(conn, headers){
                 for (prop in headers) {
                    if (headers.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                        conn.setRequestHeader(prop, headers[prop]);
                    }
                }   
            }        

            if (pub.defaultHeaders) {
                setTheHeaders(conn, pub.defaultHeaders);
            }

            if (pub.headers) {
                setTheHeaders(conn, pub.headers);
                pub.headers = null;                
            }
        }    

        // private
        function createExceptionObject(tId, callbackArg, isAbort, isTimeout) {            
            return {
                tId : tId,
                status : isAbort ? -1 : 0,
                statusText : isAbort ? 'transaction aborted' : 'communication failure',
                    isAbort: true,
                    isTimeout: true,
                argument : callbackArg
            };
        }  

        // private 
        function initHeader(label, value) {         
            (pub.headers = pub.headers || {})[label] = value;                        
        }

        // private
        function createResponseObject(o, callbackArg) {
            var headerObj = {},
                headerStr,                
                conn = o.conn;                

            try {
                headerStr = o.conn.getAllResponseHeaders();                
                Ext.each(headerStr.split('\n'), function(v){
                    var t = v.indexOf(':');
                    headerObj[v.substr(0, t)] = v.substr(t + 1);
                });
            } catch(e) {}

            return {
                tId : o.tId,
                status : conn.status,
                statusText : conn.statusText,
                getResponseHeader : function(header){return headerObj[header];},
                getAllResponseHeaders : function(){return headerStr},
                responseText : conn.responseText,
                responseXML : conn.responseXML,
                argument : callbackArg
            };
        }

        // private
        function releaseObject(o) {
            o.conn = null;
            o = null;
        }        

        // private
        function handleTransactionResponse(o, callback, isAbort, isTimeout) {
            if (!callback) {
                releaseObject(o);
                return;
            }

            var httpStatus, responseObject;

            try {
                if (o.conn.status !== undefined && o.conn.status != 0) {
                    httpStatus = o.conn.status;
                }
                else {
                    httpStatus = 13030;
                }
            }
            catch(e) {
                httpStatus = 13030;
            }

            if ((httpStatus >= 200 && httpStatus < 300) || (Ext.isIE && httpStatus == 1223)) {
                responseObject = createResponseObject(o, callback.argument);
                if (callback.success) {
                    if (!callback.scope) {
                        callback.success(responseObject);
                    }
                    else {
                        callback.success.apply(callback.scope, [responseObject]);
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                switch (httpStatus) {
                    case 12002:
                    case 12029:
                    case 12030:
                    case 12031:
                    case 12152:
                    case 13030:
                        responseObject = createExceptionObject(o.tId, callback.argument, (isAbort ? isAbort : false), isTimeout);
                        if (callback.failure) {
                            if (!callback.scope) {
                                callback.failure(responseObject);
                            }
                            else {
                                callback.failure.apply(callback.scope, [responseObject]);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        responseObject = createResponseObject(o, callback.argument);
                        if (callback.failure) {
                            if (!callback.scope) {
                                callback.failure(responseObject);
                            }
                            else {
                                callback.failure.apply(callback.scope, [responseObject]);
                            }
                        }
                }
            }

            releaseObject(o);
            responseObject = null;
        }  

        // private
        function handleReadyState(o, callback){
        callback = callback || {};
            var conn = o.conn,
                tId = o.tId,
                poll = pub.poll,
        cbTimeout = callback.timeout || null;

            if (cbTimeout) {
                pub.timeout[tId] = setTimeout(function() {
                    pub.abort(o, callback, true);
                }, cbTimeout);
            }

            poll[tId] = setInterval(
                function() {
                    if (conn && conn.readyState == 4) {
                        clearInterval(poll[tId]);
                        poll[tId] = null;

                        if (cbTimeout) {
                            clearTimeout(pub.timeout[tId]);
                            pub.timeout[tId] = null;
                        }

                        handleTransactionResponse(o, callback);
                    }
                },
                pub.pollInterval);
        }

        // private
        function asyncRequest(method, uri, callback, postData) {
            var o = getConnectionObject() || null;

            if (o) {
                o.conn.open(method, uri, true);

                if (pub.useDefaultXhrHeader) {                    
                    initHeader('X-Requested-With', pub.defaultXhrHeader);
                }

                if(postData && pub.useDefaultHeader && (!pub.headers || !pub.headers['Content-Type'])){
                    initHeader('Content-Type', pub.defaultPostHeader);
                }

                if (pub.defaultHeaders || pub.headers) {
                    setHeader(o);
                }

                handleReadyState(o, callback);
                o.conn.send(postData || null);
            }
            return o;
        }

        // private
        function getConnectionObject() {
            var o;          

            try {
                if (o = createXhrObject(pub.transactionId)) {
                    pub.transactionId++;
                }
            } catch(e) {
            } finally {
                return o;
            }
        }

        // private
        function createXhrObject(transactionId) {
            var http;

            try {
                http = new XMLHttpRequest();                
            } catch(e) {
                for (var i = 0; i < activeX.length; ++i) {                
                    try {
                        http = new ActiveXObject(activeX[i]);                        
                        break;
                    } catch(e) {}
                }
            } finally {
                return {conn : http, tId : transactionId};
            }
        }

        var pub = {
            request : function(method, uri, cb, data, options) {
                if(options){
                    var me = this,                
                        xmlData = options.xmlData,
                        jsonData = options.jsonData;

                    Ext.applyIf(me, options);            

                    if(xmlData || jsonData){
                        initHeader('Content-Type', xmlData ? 'text/xml' : 'application/json');
                        data = xmlData || Ext.encode(jsonData);
                    }
                }                        
                return asyncRequest(method || options.method || "POST", uri, cb, data);
            },

            serializeForm : function(form) {
                var fElements = form.elements || (document.forms[form] || Ext.getDom(form)).elements,
                    hasSubmit = false,
                    encoder = encodeURIComponent,
                    element,
                    options, 
                    name, 
                    val,                 
                    data = '',
                    type;

                Ext.each(fElements, function(element) {                    
                    name = element.name;                 
                    type = element.type;

                    if (!element.disabled && name){
                        if(/select-(one|multiple)/i.test(type)){                            
                            Ext.each(element.options, function(opt) {
                                if (opt.selected) {
                                    data += String.format("{0}={1}&",                                                           
                                                         encoder(name),                                                         
                                                          (opt.hasAttribute ? opt.hasAttribute('value') : opt.getAttribute('value') !== null) ? opt.value : opt.text);
                                }                                
                            });
                        } else if(!/file|undefined|reset|button/i.test(type)) {
                            if(!(/radio|checkbox/i.test(type) && !element.checked) && !(type == 'submit' && hasSubmit)){

                                data += encoder(name) + '=' + encoder(element.value) + '&';                     
                                hasSubmit = /submit/i.test(type);    
                            }                         
                        } 
                    }
                });            
                return data.substr(0, data.length - 1);
            },

            useDefaultHeader : true,
            defaultPostHeader : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            useDefaultXhrHeader : true,
            defaultXhrHeader : 'XMLHttpRequest',        
            poll : {},
            timeout : {},
            pollInterval : 50,
            transactionId : 0,
```

Comment: exact duplicate of [Error:uncaught exception, not enoughh argument.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162592/erroruncaught-exception-not-enoughh-argument).  Please don't double-post.

Comment: lol, are you serious?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably provide more arguments to the call :-) Without seeing the source (specifically line 704), there's not much else I can offer. At a bare minimum, post that line plus a little context, say five lines either side for now.

Exceptions (as in this case) generally provide enough information for you to identify both the problem and the location of the problem. You need to use that information to investigate.

A cursory glance at Google shows that the problems occur because you use things like:

```
send();
region_Table.insertRow();
```

instead of:

```
send(null);
region_Table.insertRow(0);
```

Once you post the offending line, it should be (relatively) easy to figure out.

Comment: @pravin: And what type of element is that, exactly? And which browser?

Comment: JSON, I can't help you with unfortunately other than to suggest that maybe the `.value` is incorrect. Marking CW since it's not realy helpful but I want to make sure no-one else follows the same path (or, if they do, they know enough to keep going).